# Non-blocking, CompletableFuture-based iterator

Tags: java, nonblocking

I'd like to abstract a data processing algorithm from the data extraction itself using an iterator. Like, instead of doing `dataSource.getNextObject()` just ask for a standard java.util.Iterator as input and work with that. However, JDK's `Iterator` is blocking. And using, say, Couchbase or Mongo as the data source, which have callback-based non-blocking client libraries, the blocking iterator defeats the purpose. JDK doesn't have a non-blocking one.

I've been thinking of doing a cover of `java.util.Iterator` with `hasNext()` and `next()` returning corresponding `CompletableFuture`s.

I couldn't Google up anything on the topic. Why? Is the idea too wild, am I doing something wrong?

The question is: how do you go about using iterators when blocking code isn't allowed on your project and the next/hasNext operation could block for considerable time.

**Upd:** Iterating over `CompletableFuture<E>` wouldn't work as it doesn't cover `hasNext()`, and `hasNext()` might need to actually perform a blocking operation.

Comment: What are you going to do with the futures that haven't completed? Why do you think an iterator would be the correct tool for whatever it is you want to do?

Comment: Wouldn't a `Stream` be much better and feature-rich than an `Iterator`?

Comment: For Java 7 and below, [Guava Iterables](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#iterables) could be used together with Guava's functional idioms for (lazily) transforming a datasource and encapsulating the data processing algorithm into a `Function<F,T>`. For concurrency, there's also a special Futures API called [`ListenableFuture`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Futures that don't complete have timeouts (via a single, effecient HashedWheelTimer). An iterator is a correct tool when you need to iterate over data, that just naturally comes to mind.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Never looked into implementing streams, I guess it's much more complex, but anyway I don't see how a Stream could solve the non-blocking async problem really. Also, Stream.iterator() still should return a blocking iterator.

Comment: Again, why do you think "iterating" through data where some data still doesn't exist makes sense? What is the meaning of iteration here? Do you skip the incomplete ones? Do you iterate again after a while? I can't understand the usage scenario.

Comment: Why would `hasNext()` block?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Good point. I think, from the point of view of the iterator's consumer, it doesn't matter what's behind the scenes, whether it's available or not, it just wants to lazily get data objects one by one and it could even be infinite. The iterating process stops when the underlying impl decides there are no more elements, including the case where the retrieval operation time outs.

Comment: @Kayaman For example, if you try to create an Iterator for JDBC's ResultSet you cannot check whether there's a next element without calling RS's next(), which could block.

Comment: Why don't you simply process data collecting in a separate thread with Consumer<List<Data>> callback?

Comment: @Max Number of threads shouldn't be a function of whatever happens inside the app. If everything is non-blocking then you don't need to spawn more threads than there are native ones (cores + hyperthreading).

Comment: Still can't see your usage scenario. When you iterate something, it means you have a collection of available items and you apply the same logic to all the items in the collection. I can't understand how you intend to apply any logic to nonexistent data. If you want a logic of "apply logic to item as soon as it is available", you should implement a callback mechanism, not an iterator.

Comment: @RealSkeptic The CS term "iterator" itself doesn't strictly define the underlying data as immediately available. The Java interface as well doesn't, as next() and hasNext() could block indefinitely. The only question is how to handle the waiting - block the caller's thread or give the caller a Future.

Comment: @RealSkeptic A usage scenario is the same as using a standard Java iterator - to consume elements as soon as they're available and to know whether there's something next to wait for - but without blocking the caller's thread.

Comment: The fact that they block indefinitely means that they expect the data to be available in order to perform the iteration, even if not *immediately*. Furthermore, the usual usage is that processing is stopped when `hasNext()` becomes `false`, as it is not expected to become `true` again. Doing anything else requires a polling logic which is a very bad way to handle non-synchronous operations, and a very unusual use of the `Iterator` interface (one which would fail in a `for` loop, for example).

Comment: @RealSkeptic Appreciate your input. I think what you say is exactly what an Iterator returning CF would do, what's different is how you handle the waiting. However, you couldn't use that in a regular `for` or `while` loop, you could never do that when the cycle condition depends on a future result, there are different algorithms for that. The whole point of such an iterator is to provide a recognisable abstraction to programmers: "this thing gives you data and you can tell if there's more" with the CompletableFuture quirk.